# Efficient Compositing Bitmaps over OpenCV Image Mat

Tags: opencv, gpu

I have an OpenCV program which does:

1. read images from a camera
2. do some analysis (e.g. HOG face detection)
3. mix bitmaps over the image (e.g. put a scaled/rotated HAT over the head)
4. display composited images

For this to be efficient, I am thinking that:

1. Camera images need to be read into CPU RAM because the pixels need to be read/processed by CPU
2. The overlay bitmaps should be loaded into GPU textures since it will be faster to composite them from there
3. For each frame, copy the camera image into GPU, overlay/mix the scaled/rotated overlay textures previously loaded into GPU, display

Is this thinking correct?

What OpenCV APIs (and or other libraries) can help me out here?

Not sure if this is relevant but I am using Intel GPU.